# Creating text dialogues for Javascript game

Tags: javascript, jquery, craftyjs

I have a game where you interact with NPCs, and they give multiple answers.
I've searched for tutorials and demos, but they are all mostly Unity related.

I'm fairly new to Javascript, so I'm not sure where to begin with a text dialogue
system that allows me (1)to show text on initial "hit"(which I've already been able to do), (2)give branching answers to that question, (3)and end on a certain line of text, (4)while being able to press the "Enter" key to continue the conversation.

The only way I can think of now is to use lots of If statements. But is there a much cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it would be to make a function, where the input is what the user choose:

```
function askNPC(question) {
  switch(question){
    case 'buy sword':
      return 'here you go!'; 
    break;
    case 'sell fish':
      return 'here you go!';
    break;
  }
}

var answer = askNPC('buy sword');
var answer = askNPC('sell fish');
```

Another way would be store all the questions and answers in a object:

```
var questions = {
  'buy sword': 'here you go',
  'sell fish': 'thank you'
}
function askNPC(question){
  if(typeof questions[question] !== "undefined"){
    return questions[question];
  } else {
    return 'Did not understand you question!';
  }
}

var answer = askNPC('buy sword');
var answer = askNPC('sell fish');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes look at this page about switches:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp